# Errors in .docx document creation

Tags: c#, windows-8, office-interop, word-2013

In my application I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library to create .docx file with some content from template. Everything was working correctly on Word 2010 installed (Windows 7/2008 R2) but when I tried it on Windows 8 + Word 2013 I first started to get exception codes:

```
HRESULT: 0x800706BA
HRESULT: 0x80010105
```

The thing is that after several runs of my code I got this exceptions throwed from diffrent functions (both my and Microsoft) with diffrent message like:

```
RPC server is unavailable. HRESULT: 0x800706BA at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()
Remote procedure call has failed. HRESULT: 0x800706BA at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark.get_Range()
Server threw an exception. HRESULT: 0x80010105 at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field.get_Code()
```

I read wreid things about that errors (eg. http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=136) and I'm looking for any tip.

Comment: Does it has the exception at every run or sometimes it passes?

Comment: For now at each run I gets exception similar to that I gave as example.

Comment: I read a little about this error(0x800706BA) and most likely if Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service is running in Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Services. Then it's probably firewall issue. Try to test it by temporary disabling the firewall and/or any antivirus software and retrying your actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the error 0x800706BA because file already exist in destination. Delete it before.

Vincent